# ODAC11 Oracle 9

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

We have a problem using ODAC11 (client) and Oracle databases version 9.0 and 9.1.  It returns error message ORA-604 (something about recursive error on level %).
Has anyone else collided with this problem before?

Comment: Add more details from alert.log, please. That error is too general. Original message is "ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to make sure that the client and server are compatible.  The 11 client won't reliably communicate with a server older than 10.2.0.4.

Comment: Odac is only compatible with 10g forward especially if you are using the entity framework tools beta